# Mandatory to have an iOS device to deploy in App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Actually I have this error, when I try to generate my app in XCode 12:

> ```
> Failed to create provisioning profile.
> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
> ```

And the "provisioning profile" requires an iOS device, if I'm not wrong.  I have not an iPhone/iPad this time, and (It appears) is it mandatory to create my "provisioning profile", before upload my apps in App Store.  Is that so?

Thanks on advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to at least register one Apple Device on the Apple Developer Portal. (You need one valid UUID of the device for that) You do not actually have to "own" one or test it on the device. We use one old iPhone 3GS UUID for a few customers to prevent this error.